# Where can I find info about successful payment operation in stripe dashnoard?

Tags: stripe-payments

In laravel 5.8 app with stripe/stripe-php: ^7.50 I made payment when customer to
the owner of stripe account pays for provided services with code:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY') );
$user = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->first();
$customer_id = $user->stripe_customer_id;

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                'amount' => $request->amount * 100, // Say $request->amount= 50
                'currency' => $request->currency,   // USD
                'customer' => $customer_id
            ]);
```

I made it with app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY and testing card number 4242424242424242
I did not find any info about this operation under stripe account
I tried to search under dashboard, including pages( I see “Test data” label on dashboard page. )
https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments?status%5B%5D=successful
https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/reports/hub

but failed. Where can I find info about this operation ?

Thanks!

Comment: Those payments should be under  https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments, if they are not, I would recommend double checking your API keys are from the same account that you're logging in to the Dashboard of.

Comment: Thanks!, looks like key keys were from different account